Spaces of fixed points
I am reading the paper Space with $\mathbb{G}_{m}$-action, hyperbolic localization and nearby cycles by Timo Richarz and I am having some troubles in understanding the proof of Lemma 1.10.
The setting is as follows. Let $S$ be a scheme and $U \longrightarrow X$ be a morphism of $S$-algebraic spaces endowed with $\mathbb{G}_{m,S}$-actions. Lemma 1.10 in loc. cit. says that if $u \colon U \longrightarrow X$ is étale then $U^0 = U \times_X X^0$ where $(-)^0$ denotes the functor of fixed points (of the given $\mathbb{G}_{m,S}$-actions).
In case $U \longrightarrow X$ is an open immersion, the lemma seems to be obvious but I could not understand the proof of the étale case. Here the proof: let $T/S$ be a scheme with trivial $\mathbb{G}_{m,S}$-action and an equivariant morphism $T \longrightarrow X$. Given a morphism $\widetilde{f} \colon T \longrightarrow U$ such that $u \circ \widetilde{f} = f$, then the problem is to prove that $\widetilde{f}$ is equivariant.

The author claims that it suffices to prove that $\widetilde{f}$ is locally étale equivariant.
If $T$ is the spectrum of a strictly henselian local ring then $\widetilde{f}$ is equivariant because $\mathbb{G}_{m,S}$ is connected and $u$ is étale.
Finally, he finishes the proof by some limit argument.

Since I am not really familiar with neither algebraic spaces nor algebraic groups, I hope you can help me to understand the proof or give me some references for each of my confusions. Thank you in advance.

You may be interested in the Appendix to the paper "Algebraic Magnetism" my Arnaud Mayeux, see http://arxiv.org/abs/2203.08231v3. It contains a generalization as well as more detailed proofs.

Hi Matthieu, it is probably too generalized for me. I found an argument by Alper in the case of algebraic spaces over a field. The problem reduces to: if $ U \to X$ is an open immersion of spaces with $G$-actions ($G$: connected), then by connectedness, any $G$-orbit $Gu$ ($u \in U$) is connected, hence $U$ is $G$-invariant. I do not really understand the last conclusion. I think somehow you made a similar argument to this in the appendix.

Well, but saying that $i:U\to X$ is an open immersion and $G$-equivariant means that $U$ (seen as a subspace of $X$) is $G$-invariant, doesn't it?
